# Specflow tutorials which cover UI testing

Tags: c#, test-automation-framework, specflow

When initially delving into the realm of BDD my initial foray was with Java and Cucumber. I found a wealth of knowledge online which allowed me to get to grips with this, specifically real-world scenarios where, for example, I’d log into an website and carry out some basic functionality.

I’ve since moved across to coding in C# and as a result am looking at utilizing Specflow. Unfortunately, I’ve found that there isn’t as much information as there is for Cucumber. There are a lot of basic courses, but the stuff I’m looking for relates to the more in-depth functions such as using Hooks, data tables etc.

I was wondering if anyone has any useful links that they can send over for Specflow tutorials/courses as I’d be interested going through them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Andy.
I found this pretty attractive course on udemy with greate feedbacks
https://www.udemy.com/framework-development-with-selenium-csharp-advanced/
and there are other good courses. Explore it.
Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Specflow has some great learning content.
https://docs.specflow.org/projects/getting-started/en/latest/index.html#
https://specflow.org/learn/bdd/

Here is some table info:
https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow/en/latest/Bindings/SpecFlow-Assist-Helpers.html

Specflow youtube channel:  https://www.youtube.com/c/SpecFlowBDD/videos

The ExecuteAutomation channel on youtube has some good videos as well.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O5oHiBD5Lvk

Automate the planet site has good info, here is an article on hooks:
https://www.automatetheplanet.com/extend-test-execution-workflow-specflow-hooks/

As does GitHub.  Try some searches there for what you are looking for.  Here is an example of a search I did for specflow hook and c#:
https://github.com/search?l=C%23&q=specflow+hook&type=Repositories

Good luck.  There is a lot of info out there.